# Maven / eclipse project structure

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, project-management

I am still fairly new to Maven, I finally have it how I want but now I need to break it all over again.

Here is my scenario:

I need to write two different server applications, which use identical core functionality; just, what is done with that framework is very different. One server application is very easy/simple - it's already done - whereas the other is a lot more complicated.

The code is written in a dependency injection style (using Guice, if it matters), so it should be extremely easy to break apart.

My question is this: how would you structure the projects in Eclipse, using Maven? Would you set up three different projects, something like:

```
server-core
server-appEasy
server-appComplicated
```

where each server would have it's own pom. Or, would you keep it all in one project? I need to be able to easily recompile `appEasy` in, say, a month from now, while I work on `appComplicated`. The classes for `appEasy` are already in a subpackage. Note: `core` would not work by itself without at least a mock dependency injection. It doesn't have a `main` class.

All thoughts appreciated, even on things I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a structure like this:

```
/server
    /server-core
        pom.xml
    /server-appeasy
        pom.xml
    /server-appcomplicated
        pom.xml
    pom.xml
```

So each project has its own pom.xml that allows you to build that project in isolation.

However the parent folder also has a pom.xml, which will build all the projects if run. You can do this by including the projects as modules in the parent pom.

E.g. In the parent pom.xml

```
<modules>
    <module>server-core</module>
    <module>server-appeasy</module>
    <module>server-appcomplicated</module>
</modules>
```

You can also use managed dependencies in the parent pom tio allow you to centralise external dependency and plugin version numbers.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who suggested Module projects, it seems to be what I need. I didn't know about that feature. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to structure all as a Maven Multi Module project.

The parent project, would have the three projects as modules, the 3th party dependency  versions, and the version of your project as a property.

Then, in the server-appComplicated and server-appEasy I would add a dependecy to the server-core.

In this way you will gain:
1- A root project to compile (the parent), that it will generate the two servers and the core-lib.
2- A point where to handle the version numbers and the common dependencies.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Im not a maven expert but here is my 2 cents. 
Each project needs its own pom. 
Do you need to build all the projects together? In that case it might make sense to have a parent pom , which has all the common dependencies.

EDIT: In that case, I feel just have three separate 3 pom files for each project.

Comment: Now that the easy project is done, I probably won't be building it very often. I just need to be able to, in case I need to tweak it

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, depending on how you need it when it comes to deployment.  Assuming that 'server-core' is a shared artifacts among your 'server-appEasy' and 'server-appComplicated' artifacts, I would suggest something as below

1. Create a Maven Project 'server-core'
2. Add two module projects
   by name 'server-appEasy' and 'server-appComplicated'
3. Make sure the module projects have their parent set as the 'server-core'
4. In the end you should have three projects (each has separate pom.xml), where
   a. Building 'server-core' will also build the modules
   b. Building either of the 'easy' and 'complicated' modules independently on need basis will also build the server-core.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think this will work because the parent project should have packaging "pom", right?

Comment: You are right, answer by 'cowls' is what you might want to do and what I had in mind.